# Numerically solving a non-linear integro-differential equation

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, integral-equations

I am interested in solving the non-linear integro-differential equation
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d} y}{\mathrm{d} \tau} = - \int_{0}^{\tau} \mathrm{d} s \, \big[ y(\tau -s) \big]^{2} y(s) ; \quad y (0) = 1 .
$$
I believe that there is no known analytical closed form solution(?) So I wanted to rely on numerical methods, and wrote

```
eqn = y'[tau] == - Integrate[y[tau-s] y[tau-s] y[s],{s,0,tau}];
init = y[0] == 1;
sol = NDSolveValue[{eqn,init},y,{tau,0,10}];
```

From the error messages, it seems that `NDSolveValue` cannot handle such an integro-differential equation. Would there be any easy work-arounds to solve this equation numerically using Mathematica?

Comment: This  [ndsolve-integro-differential-equation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/172931/ndsolve-integro-differential-equation) is similar question. unfortunately  the nice trick shown there by Carl Woll does not work here since your integrand has $y$ that depends on both delayed input and also not delayed input. If your $y$ inside the integrand depended only on delayed input, then Carl's trick would have worked by replacing $t=\tau-s$ as shown in the above. So my guess is that this can not be solved by NDSolve as it stands but I could be wrong.

Comment: With MellinTransform I have only a general solution:`y[tau] = -E^(I tau) C[1] - E^(-I tau) C[2]`.

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk  what is `C[1]` and `C[2]` in the above? constant of integrations? But this is first order ode, should the solution not only have one constant of integration?

Comment: @Nasser I used example from help pages of **MellinTransform**. Try:`eqn = y'[tau] == -Integrate[y[tau - s]^2*y[s], {s, 0, tau}]; F = 
 MellinTransform[eqn, tau, q] /. y[0] -> 1; R = 
 RSolveValue[F, MellinTransform[y[tau], tau, q], q]; 
InverseMellinTransform[R, q, tau] // Expand`

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk: Unfortunately, `eqn /. {y[tau] -> E^(I tau), y'[tau] -> D[E^(I tau), tau], 
  y[s] -> E^(I s), y[tau - s] -> E^(I (tau - s))}` results in `I E^(I tau) == I E^(I tau) (-1 + E^(I tau))` which is not true. Hope I am not mistaken.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a very inefficient way to solve it (*because of re-interpolation and recalculations in the `NIntegrate`*). I'm no expert on differential equation solving, but thought it would be worth sharing a very naïve approach to this because it's surprisingly brief and requires little expert knowledge:

```
next[pts_, d_] := 
 With[{i = Interpolation[Normal@pts, InterpolationOrder -> 1],
   p = pts["Part", -1]},
  With[{x0 = p[[1]], y0 = p[[2]]},
   With[{g = -NIntegrate[i[x0 - s]^2 i[s], {s, 0, x0}]},
    pts["Append", {x0 + d, y0 + d*g}]
    ]]]

points = CreateDataStructure["DynamicArray"];
points["Append", {0, 1}];
With[{n = 100},
 result = Nest[next[#, 10./n] &, points, n];
 ListLinePlot[Normal@result, PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, {-0.2, 1.1}}, 
  Frame -> True]]
```

[image]

Comment: This is very nice code (+1).

Comment: I can recommend option `InterpolationOrder -> 0` and `n=200` then it consider with my solution.

Answer (score 11):

This equation can be solved numerically using method described in our [paper](https://www.mdpi.com/1099-4300/22/8/824?type=check_update&version=1). First note, that integral $\int_{0}^{\tau} \mathrm{d} s \, \big[ y(\tau -s) \big]^{2} y(s) $ can be mapped on (-1,1) by substitution $s=\tau/2 (1+z)$, therefore

```
int[tau_] := 
  tau/2 Integrate[y[tau/2 (1 - z)]^2 y[tau/2 (1 + z)], {z, -1, 1}];
```

In turn `int` can be integrated using Gauss quadrature, for this we call

```
Get["NumericalDifferentialEquationAnalysis`"];
```

To convert integrodifferential equation into system of algebraic equations we use the Euler wavelets as follows

```
UE[m_, t_] := EulerE[m, t];
psi[k_, n_, m_, t_] := 
  Piecewise[{{2^(k/2)  UE[m, 2^k t - 2 n + 1], (n - 1)/2^(k - 1) <= t < 
      n/2^(k - 1)}, {0, True}}];
PsiE[k_, M_, t_] := 
 Flatten[Table[psi[k, n, m, t], {n, 1, 2^(k - 1)}, {m, 0, M - 1}]]
k0 = 4; M0 = 7; With[{k = k0, M = M0}, 
 nn = Length[Flatten[Table[1, {n, 1, 2^(k - 1)}, {m, 0, M - 1}]]]];
dx = 1/(nn); xl = Table[l*dx, {l, 0, nn}]; xcol = 
 Table[(xl[[l - 1]] + xl[[l]])/2, {l, 2, nn + 1}]; Psijk = 
 With[{k = k0, M = M0}, PsiE[k, M, t1]]; Int1 = 
 With[{k = k0, M = M0}, Integrate[PsiE[k, M, t1], t1]];
Psi[x_] := Psijk /. t1 -> x; 
int1[x_] := Int1 /. t1 -> x; var = Array[a, {nn}]; 
y[t_] := var . int1[t] + a0 ; dy[t_] := var . Psi[t];

np = nn; g = GaussianQuadratureWeights[np, -1, 1]; points = 
 g[[All, 1]];
weights = g[[All, 2]];
Int[ff_, z_] := 
 Sum[(ff /. z -> points[[i]])*weights[[i]], {i, 1, np}]; 
intNum[tau_] := tau/2 Int[y[tau/2 (1 - z)]^2 y[tau/2 (1 + z)], z];
T=10;eqs = Table[dy[t]/T + T intNum[t] == 0, {t, xcol}];
```

To solve system `eqs` with initial condition `y[0]==1` we use

```
 eqAll = Join[eqs, {y[0] == 1}]; varAll = Join[{a0}, var]; vv = 
 Table[{varAll[[i]], 1/10}, {i, Length[varAll]}]; sol = 
 FindRoot[eqAll, vv];
```

Visualization

```
Plot[y[t/T] /. sol, {t, 0, T}, PlotRange -> All, 
 FrameLabel -> {"\[Tau]", "y"}, Frame -> True]
```

[image: Figure 1]

**Update 1** We can compare this solution with that proposed by flinty at `n=200` (red points) as follows

```
next[pts_, d_] := 
 With[{i = Interpolation[Normal@pts, InterpolationOrder -> 0], 
   p = pts["Part", -1]}, 
  With[{x0 = p[[1]], y0 = p[[2]]}, 
   With[{g = -NIntegrate[i[x0 - s]^2 i[s], {s, 0, x0}]}, 
    pts["Append", {x0 + d, y0 + d*g}]]]]

points = CreateDataStructure["DynamicArray"];
points["Append", {0, 1}];
With[{n = 200}, result = Nest[next[#, 10./n] &, points, n];
 pl = ListPlot[Normal@result, PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, {-0.2, 1.1}}, 
   Frame -> True, PlotStyle -> Red]]

Show[Plot[y[t/T] /. sol, {t, 0, T}, PlotRange -> All, 
  FrameLabel -> {"\[Tau]", "y"}, Frame -> True], pl]
```

[image: Figure 2]

**Update 2.** We also can compare our solution with solution proposed by Ulrich as follows (please, pay attention that his code has been updated with `int` and initial data)

```
nl = NestList[
   Function[{fa}, 
    Block[{int, ip}, 
     int[tau_?NumericQ] := 
      Block[{s}, 
       NIntegrate[
        fa[tau - s] fa''[tau - s] fa[s] + 
         fa'[tau - s] fa'[tau - s] fa[s], {s, 0, tau}, 
        Method -> {{Automatic, "LocalAdaptive"}[[-1]], 
          "SymbolicProcessing" -> 0}]];
     NDSolveValue[{f'''[tau] == - f'[tau] - 2 int[tau], f[0] == 1, 
       f'[0] == 0, f''[0] == -1}, f, {tau, 0, 10}]]], Exp[-#^2] &, 10];
pl1=Plot[nl[[-1]][t], {t, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> All, 
 PlotStyle -> {Red, Dashed}]
 Show[Plot[y[t/T] /. sol, {t, 0, T}, PlotRange -> All, 
      FrameLabel -> {"\[Tau]", "y"}, Frame -> True], pl1]
```

[image: Figure 3]

Comment: I tried yours code it dosen't work properly? `a0` ?

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk Thank you. There is a typo in the code with `psi` definition. Please try new version.

Comment: Ok Works fine. Thanks

Comment: @AlexTrounev, Sir, sorry to bother you here! Could you please have a look at my recent post? It is an interesting problem with a working code. Thank you for the previously invaluable help!

Answer (score 5):

In addition to the interesting answers from Alex Trounev and flinty here I show an iterative solution procedure of the differentiated  integro-differential equation using `NestList`, `NIntegrate` and `NDSolveValue`

[image]

with bc `y[0]==1, y'[0]==0`

```
nl = NestList[
Function[{fa}, 
Block[{int, ip },
int[tau_?NumericQ] := Block[{s},
NIntegrate[ fa [tau - s] fa '[tau - s] fa [s], {s, 0, tau }, 
Method -> {{Automatic, "LocalAdaptive"}[[-1]],"SymbolicProcessing"-> 0} ]];
NDSolveValue[{ f'' [ tau] == -f[tau]  - 2 int[tau], 
f[0] == 1,f'[0] == 0}, f, {tau, 0 , 10} ]]
], 1 &, 10];

  Plot[nl[[-1]][t], {t, 0, 10} ,PlotRange -> {-.1, 1}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Dashed}]
```

[image]

which fits quite well with the solutions found in the other answers.

Unfortunately at `tau~7` we see numerical problems in the iteration process, which I don't understand yet.

Comment: It is a nice attempt (+1). We can compute right solution with this code. See Update 2 to my answer.

Comment: @AlexTrounev clever idea to differentiate one more time. Thank you!

Comment: @AlexTrounev clever idea to differentiate one more time. Thank you! Still I'm wondering why my attempt suddenly diverges.

Comment: It is not wondering that solution with your code diverges. But it is unexplained that my solution with updated code converges.  Normally solution with iterative method diverges in a case of nonlinear integrodifferential equations.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another solution using the trapezoidal rule for the time integral in the rhs, and a second-order predictor-corrector for the differential equation:

```
(*Computes Integrate[-f[\[Tau]-s]^2 f[\[Tau]],{\[Tau],0,T}] using the \
trapezoidal rule.*)
computeIntegral[] := Module[{n, int},
   int = dt (0.5  tab[[-1]]^2 tab[[1]] + 0.5 tab[[-1]] tab[[1]]^2);
   int += dt Sum[tab[[-1 - i + 1]]^2 tab[[i]], {i, 2, Length@tab - 1}];
   -int
   ];
(*Time-integration using a second-order predictor-corrector.*)
update[] := Module[{int, pred, intnew, corr},
   int = computeIntegral[];
   pred = tab[[-1]] + dt int;
   AppendTo[tab, pred];
   intnew = computeIntegral[];
   corr = tab[[-2]] + 0.5 dt (int + intnew);
   tab[[-1]] = corr;
   ];
```

The solution is then obtained via

```
dt = 0.1;
tab = {1.0};
Do[
  update[];
  , {i, 1, 100}];
(*.*)
tabt = Table[i dt, {i, 0, 100}];
ListPlot[{tabt, tab} // Transpose, PlotRange -> Full]
```

[image]