# Numerically integrating of solution in NDSolve

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration

I am trying to solve the following differential equations: \begin{align} \dot{a}(\tau) &= \frac{a(\tau)}{\sqrt{3}}\left[
                 \rho_R(\tau) + \rho_V(\tau) 
                 \right]^{1/2}\\[0.25cm] \dot{\rho}_R(\tau) &+ 4\frac{\dot{a}(\tau)}{a(\tau)}\rho_R(\tau)=-\dot{\rho}_V(\tau) \end{align} with the initial conditions $$ a(\tau = 0) = 1,\qquad \rho_R(\tau = 0) = 1.  $$ The function $\rho_V(\tau)$ is the source of all of the problems. It is of the form $\rho_V(r) = \exp(-I(\tau))$, where $$ I(\tau)
= \frac{4\pi}{3} \int_{0}^{\tau}\Gamma(\tau')a^3(\tau')R^3(\tau', \tau)\ d\tau' $$ and $$ R(\tau', \tau) = \int_{\tau'}^\tau \frac{d\tau''}{a(\tau'')}, \qquad \Gamma(\tau) = \Gamma_0e^{\beta\tau} $$ Let $\Gamma_0 = \beta = 1$ for simplicity.

I am having trouble integrating this code using `NDSolve` since the integrals depend on $a(\tau)$. I would imagine that this is possible to evaluate since the integration only occurs until the currently evaluated time-step, but I am unsure how to do so. Below is my best attempt, but it doesn't work.

The key issue, is that I am unsure how to pass $a(\tau)$ into the function `Ii` so that I can perform the integration. Thanks for the help!

```
Γ[t_] := Γ0*Exp[β*t] ; Γ0 = 1; β = 1;

Rr[p_?NumericQ, _?NumericQ, A_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[1/A, {t, p, }];
Ii[_?NumericQ,  A_] := (4*Pi)/3 NIntegrate[Γ[p]*A^3 Rr[p, , A]^3, {p, 0, }];

V[_ , A_?NumericQ] = Exp[-Ii[,  A]];
0 = 0; f = 50;
eqs = {
   a'[] == a[]/Sqrt[3]*Sqrt[R[] + V[, a[]]],
   R'[] + 4*a'[]/a[] R[] == -D[V[, a[]], ],
   R[0] == 1, a[0] == 1
   };

sols = NDSolve[eqs, {, 0, f}];
```

**Update 1**

@Alex Trounev has seemed to produce many solutions, all of which agree with each other. I tried to develop another solution, which seems to get close but isn't quite the same as the three results below.

Much like, @Alex Trounev I defined

\begin{equation} R(\tau) = \int_0^\tau \frac{d \tau'}{a(\tau')},  \qquad \dot{R}(\tau) = \frac{1}{a(\tau)} . \end{equation}

Given $I(\tau)$ above, you can expand the cubic term and then define four variables

\begin{equation} v_i(\tau) = \int_{0}^{\tau}\Gamma(\tau')a^3(\tau) R^i(\tau)\ d\tau \end{equation}

each of which corresponds to the differential equation

\begin{equation} \dot{v}_i(\tau) = \Gamma(\tau')a^3(\tau) R^i(\tau), \qquad i = 0,1,2,3 \end{equation}

This allows us to write the function $I(\tau)$ as

\begin{equation} I(\tau) = \frac{4\pi}{3}\left\{ R^3(\tau)v_0(\tau) - 3R^2(\tau)v_1(\tau) + 3R(\tau)v_2(\tau) + v_3(\tau) \right\} . \end{equation}

The initial conditions for each $v_i(\tau = 0) = 0$. I tried integrating this system (see below). While I get a similar result, the height of the peak is significantly different. It also seems like there is an issue with `Gam0 = 1`. I'm not particularly sure what is causing the cusp at `t ~ 2`.

I am not sure where my error is here, so any input would be appreciated.

```
Gam[t_] := Gam0*Exp[beta*t] ; Gam0 = 1; beta = 1;

t0 = 0; tf = 4;
Ii[t_] := (4 Pi)/
   3 (Rr[t]^3 v0[t]  - 3* Rr[t]^2 v1[t] + 3* Rr[t]*v2[t] - v3[t]);
eqs = {
   a'[t] == a[t]/Sqrt[3]*Sqrt[rhoR[t] + Exp[-Ii[t]]],
   rhoR'[t] + 4*a'[t]/a[t] rhoR[t] == -D[Exp[-Ii[t]], t],
   Rr'[t] == 1/a[t],
   v0'[t] == Gam[t]*a[t]^3,
   v1'[t] == Gam[t]*a[t]^3*Rr[t],
   v2'[t] == Gam[t]*a[t]^3*Rr[t]^2,
   v3'[t] == Gam[t]*a[t]^3*Rr[t]^3,
   rhoR[t0] == 1,
   a[t0] == 1,
   Rr[t0] == 0,
   v0[t0] == 0,
   v1[t0] == 0, 
   v2[t0] == 0,
   v3[t0] == 0 
   };

sols = NDSolve[eqs, {a, rhoR, Rr, v0, v1, v2, v3}, {t, t0, tf},
   WorkingPrecision -> MachinePrecision];
```

[image]

**Update 2**

My issues was one rouge minus sign in front of `v3` (corrected above). The code now reproduces @Alex Trounev's quite well. Problem solved!

### [image]

Comment: We can solve this problem using method described in my answer on https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/285076/numerically-solving-a-non-linear-integro-differential-equation/285096#285096

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can solve this problem using method described in my answer [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/285076/numerically-solving-a-non-linear-integro-differential-equation/285096#285096https://). First we transform model to the system of 3 equations using equation $R'=1/a$. Hence we have
\begin{align} \dot{a}(\tau) &= \frac{a(\tau)}{\sqrt{3}}\left[
                 \rho_R(\tau) + \rho_V(\tau) 
                 \right]^{1/2}\\[0.25cm] \dot{\rho}_R(\tau) &+ 4\frac{\dot{a}(\tau)}{a(\tau)}\rho_R(\tau)=-\dot{\rho}_V(\tau)
                   \\[0.25cm] \dot{R}(\tau) &= \frac{1}{a(\tau)} \end{align}
with updated initial conditions

$a(0) = 1,\qquad \rho_R(0) = 1,\qquad R(0)=0.$

We define integral $I(\tau)$ as

$I(\tau)
= \frac{4\pi}{3} \int_{0}^{\tau}\Gamma(\tau')a^3(\tau')(R(\tau)-R(\tau'))^3\ d\tau'$

First derivative of this integral is given by

$I_1=I'(\tau)
= 4\pi \int_{0}^{\tau}\Gamma(\tau')(a^3(\tau')/a(\tau))(R(\tau)-R(\tau'))^2\ d\tau'$

Then we map $I, I_1$ on $(-1,1)$ using substitution $\tau'=\frac{1}{2} \tau(1+z)$. Last integrals we compute using Gauss quadrature rule, for this we call

```
 Get["NumericalDifferentialEquationAnalysis`"];
```

Code to solve the problem for $0\le \tau\le 4$

```
UE[m_, t_] := EulerE[m, t];
psi[k_, n_, m_, t_] := 
  Piecewise[{{2^(k/2) UE[m, 2^k t - 2 n + 1], (n - 1)/2^(k - 1) <= t <
       n/2^(k - 1)}, {0, True}}];
PsiE[k_, M_, t_] := 
 Flatten[Table[psi[k, n, m, t], {n, 1, 2^(k - 1)}, {m, 0, M - 1}]]
k0 = 3; M0 = 6; With[{k = k0, M = M0}, 
 nn = Length[Flatten[Table[1, {n, 1, 2^(k - 1)}, {m, 0, M - 1}]]]];
dx = 1/(nn); xl = Table[l*dx, {l, 0, nn}]; xcol = 
 Table[(xl[[l - 1]] + xl[[l]])/2, {l, 2, nn + 1}]; Psijk = 
 With[{k = k0, M = M0}, PsiE[k, M, t1]]; In1 = 
 With[{k = k0, M = M0}, Integrate[PsiE[k, M, t1], t1]];
Psi[x_] := Psijk /. t1 -> x;
in1[x_] := In1 /. t1 -> x; var1 = Array[aa, {nn}]; var2 = 
 Array[b, {nn}]; var3 = Array[c, {nn}];
a[t_] := var1 . in1[t] + a0; a1[t_] := var1 . Psi[t]; 
rhoR[t_] := var2 . in1[t] + b0; rhoR1[t_] := var2 . Psi[t]; 
R[t_] := var3 . in1[t] + c0; R1[t_] := var3 . Psi[t];

np = nn; g = GaussianQuadratureWeights[np, -1, 1]; points = 
 g[[All, 1]];
weights = g[[All, 2]];
Int[ff_, z_] := Sum[(ff /. z -> points[[i]])*weights[[i]], {i, 1, np}];
intNum[t_] := 
  t 2 Pi/3 Int[
    Exp[t/2 (1 + z)] a[t/2 (1 + z)]^3 (R[t] - R[t/2 (1 + z)])^3, z];

int1Num[t_] := 
  t 2 Pi Int[
    Exp[t/2 (1 + z)] (a[t/2 (1 + z)]^3/
       a[t]) (R[t] - R[t/2 (1 + z)])^2, z];

T = 4; eqs = 
 Table[{a1[t]/T == a[t]/Sqrt[3]*Sqrt[rhoR[t] + Exp[-T intNum[t]]], 
    rhoR1[t]/T + 4*a1[t]/a[t] rhoR[t]/T == 
     T int1Num[t] Exp[-T intNum[t]], R1[t]/T == 1/a[t]}, {t, xcol}] //
   Flatten;
```

Solution

```
{a0 = 1, b0 = 1, c0 = 0}; var = Join[var1, var2, var3]; sol = 
 FindRoot[eqs, Table[{var[[i]], 1/10}, {i, Length[var]}], 
  MaxIterations -> 10000];
```

Visualization

```
{Plot[Evaluate[a[t/T] /. sol], {t, 0, T}, 
  AxesLabel -> {"\[Tau]", "a"}], 
 Plot[Evaluate[rhoR[t/T] /. sol], {t, 0, T}, 
  AxesLabel -> {"\[Tau]", "\[Rho]R"}], 
 Plot[Evaluate[R[t/T] /. sol], {t, 0, T}, 
  AxesLabel -> {"\[Tau]", "R"}]}
```

[image: Figure 1]

**Update 1.** We can also use method proposed by Ulrich Neumann and adopted for this problem as follows

```
nl1 = NestList[
   Function[{fa}, 
    Block[{int, int1, fR}, 
     int[tau_?NumericQ] := 
      Block[{s}, 
       4 Pi/3 NIntegrate[
         Exp[s] fa[[1]][s]^3 (fR[s, tau])^3, {s, 0, tau}, 
         Method -> {{Automatic, "LocalAdaptive"}[[-1]], 
           "SymbolicProcessing" -> 0}]]; 
     int1[tau_?NumericQ] := 
      Block[{s}, 
       4 Pi NIntegrate[
         Exp[s] fa[[1]][s]^3/fa[[1]][tau] (fR[s, tau])^2, {s, 0, tau},
          Method -> {{Automatic, "LocalAdaptive"}[[-1]], 
           "SymbolicProcessing" -> 0}]]; 
     fR[s_?NumericQ, tau_?NumericQ] := 
      Block[{s1}, 
       NIntegrate[1/fa[[1]][s1], {s1, s, tau}, 
        Method -> {{Automatic, "LocalAdaptive"}[[-1]], 
          "SymbolicProcessing" -> 0}]];
     NDSolveValue[{ae'[tau] == 
        ae[tau]/Sqrt[3]*Sqrt[rhoRe[tau] + Exp[-int[tau]]], 
       rhoRe'[tau] + 4*ae'[tau]/ae[tau] rhoRe[tau] == 
        int1[tau] Exp[-int[tau]], rhoRe[0] == 1, ae[0] == 1}, {ae, 
       rhoRe}, {tau, 0, 4}]]], {1, 1}, 5];
```

Here we use 5 iterations only since it takes a time. To compare with wavelets method we use

```
pl={Show[Plot[Evaluate[a[t/T] /. sol], {t, 0, T}, 
  AxesLabel -> {"\[Tau]", "a"}, PlotStyle -> Blue],Plot[Table[nl1[[i]][[1]][t], {i, 4, 5}], {t, 0, T}, PlotRange -> All, 
 PlotStyle -> {Red, Dashed}]], Show[Evaluate[rhoR[t/T] /. sol], {t, 0, T}, 
 AxesLabel -> {"\[Tau]", "\[Rho]R"}, PlotRange -> All], Plot[Table[nl1[[i]][[2]][t], {i, 4, 5}], {t, 0, T}, PlotRange -> All, 
 PlotStyle -> {Red, Dashed}]]}
```

[image: Figure 2]

In this picture we see unexplained discrepancies. Maybe we need third code to compare with.

**Update 2.** Third code is given by (this is appropriate modification code proposed by flinty)

```
next[pts_, d_] := 
  With[{np = Normal[pts]}, 
   With[{a = 
      Interpolation[Transpose[{np[[All, 1]], np[[All, 2]]}], 
       InterpolationOrder -> 0], p = pts["Part", -1], 
     rhoR = Interpolation[Transpose[{np[[All, 1]], np[[All, 3]]}], 
       InterpolationOrder -> 0], 
     R = Interpolation[Transpose[{np[[All, 1]], np[[All, 4]]}], 
       InterpolationOrder -> 0]}, 
    With[{x0 = p[[1]], a0 = p[[2]], rhoR0 = p[[3]], R0 = p[[4]]}, 
     With[{int = 
        4 Pi/3 NIntegrate[Exp[s] a[s]^3 (R[x0] - R[s])^3, {s, 0, x0}, 
          Method -> {{Automatic, "LocalAdaptive"}[[-1]], 
            "SymbolicProcessing" -> 0}], 
       int1 = 4 Pi NIntegrate[
          Exp[s] a[s]^3 /a[x0] (R[x0] - R[s])^2, {s, 0, x0}, 
          Method -> {{Automatic, "LocalAdaptive"}[[-1]], 
            "SymbolicProcessing" -> 0}]}, 
      pts["Append", {x0 + d, 
        a0 + d*(a[x0]/Sqrt[3]*Sqrt[rhoR[x0] + Exp[-int]]), 
        rhoR0 + d*(int1 Exp[-int] - 
            4*(a[x0]/Sqrt[3]*Sqrt[rhoR[x0] + Exp[-int]])/a[x0] rhoR[
              x0]), R0 + d/a[x0]}]]]]];


points = CreateDataStructure["DynamicArray"];
points["Append", {0, 1, 1, 0}];
With[{n = 200}, result = Nest[next[#, 4./n] &, points, n]];

sol1 = Normal[result];
```

As we can see `next` is the Euler step implementation. Visualization

```
pl1 = ListPlot[Transpose[{sol1[[All, 1]], sol1[[All, 2]]}], 
  Frame -> True, PlotStyle -> {Green, PointSize[.005]}];
pl2 = ListPlot[Transpose[{sol1[[All, 1]], sol1[[All, 2]]}], 
  Frame -> True, PlotStyle -> {Green, PointSize[.005]}];
{Show[pl[[1]],pl1],Show[pl[[2]],pl2]}
```

[image: Figure 3]
The resume is that wavelets method probably has large error since we use 24 collocation points only.

With the last code we can compute solution up to $\tau =50$ as follows

```
With[{n = 500}, result = Nest[next[#, 50./n] &, points, n]];
```

Visualization
[image: Figure 4]