# Solution of an integral equation

Tags: equation-solving, numerical-integration, integral-equations

I want to numerically solve the following integral equation for $A(x)$ (where $A: \mathbb{R}\mapsto\mathbb{R}^+$):
$$A(x)=\exp{\left(-\int_{-x}^{\infty} (x+y)^r A(y) dy\right)},$$

where $r\in\mathbb{N}$ (I am interested in $r=1,2$). Moreover I know that $A(-\infty)=1$ and $A(+\infty)=0$. What I expect is a unique solution also for the cases $r=1$ and $r=2$.

I tried something using FindRoot:

```
precision = 4;
Maxit = 300;
accuracy = Round[precision/2];
r = 1;
fun[x_?NumericQ, A_?NumericQ] := 
  A - Exp[-NIntegrate[(x+y)^r A, {y, -x, Infinity}, 
      WorkingPrecision -> precision, AccuracyGoal -> accuracy, 
      PrecisionGoal -> precision, 
      Method -> {Automatic, "SymbolicProcessing" -> 0}]];
Afun[x_?NumericQ] := 
 FindRoot[fun[x, z], {z, 0.2}, MaxIterations -> Maxit][[1]][[2]]
data = Table[{x, Afun[x]}, {x, -10, 10, 0.5}]
A = Interpolation[DeleteDuplicates[data]];
Plot[A[x], {x, -10, 10}] Afun[x_?NumericQ] := 
 FindRoot[fun[x, z], {z, 0.2}, MaxIterations -> Maxit][[1]][[2]]
```

but this cannot clearly give the solution, since the function $A(x)$ depends on the integral variable. Can anyone help me?

Moreover I am referring to this question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4728120/solution-of-a-simple-integral-equation/4728209#4728209 . Here the equation for $r=0$ is solved analytically, but for $r=1$ and $r=2$ it seems impossible to tackle analytically the problem, so that I tried numerically. Maybe it is easier to solve the corresponding differential equation (which can be found deriving both sides).

Comment: Where does condition `A[Infinity]==0` come from?

Comment: In the problem I am studying $1-A(x)$ is the cumulative distribution function of a density which has support on the real line, that's why the two conditions.

Comment: `DSolve` can solve some integral equations exactly in Mathematica, but unsurprisingly (given the non-linearity) it returns unevaluated on this one.  Unfortunately, it does not appear that `NDSolve` can do anything with integral equations.

Comment: Yes. I tried also with NDSolve but in this case it doesn't give any reasonable solution.

Comment: What happened to the `x+y` in the integrand?

Comment: Sorry, I was trying the $r=0$ case, I will edit the code.

Comment: Perhaps, with `A[x,r]:= A[x]...` , knowing `A[x,0]=1/(1+Exp[x])`, the recursion `D[Log[A[x,r]],r]==r Log[A[x,r-1] , r,1,2,...`  might give a solution???

Comment: That's interesting. I have the analytical solution for $A[x,0]$ (which is described in the link I provided) so maybe I can solve the case $r=1$ and then $r=2$ and so on?

Comment: Yes that's the idea. You *only* have to solve the recursion ode for arbitrary r.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That is a brilliant idea! Maybe I found what I was searching for. I check some things and if this method is correct I will post an answer giving you the credit for your intuition.

Comment: Good luck. Unfortunately the next days I don't have Mathematica access...

Comment: Another idea might be an iterative approach. Therefore it would be helpful if the definition range of `x,y` and the `integration range` might be transformed in a finite intervall...

Comment: @UlrichNeumann unfortunately it seems not possible to write a recursive relation. Defining $A_r(x)\equiv \exp{\left(-\int_{-x}^{\infty}(x+y)^rA_r(x)\right)}$ and deriving $\log{\left(A_r(x)\right)}$ it does not come out $A_{r-1}$.

Comment: @UlrichNeumann for the iterative solution the upper limit ($\infty$) can be set to a large but finite limit, since $A(x)$ goes to zero for $x$ large. However I don’t have an idea on how to implement the iterative solution, can you give some hints about?

Comment: @yarchik Please reopen your answer for the case `r==1`if possible.

Comment: Your integral equation is very interesting. It can be solved accurately by reduction to a system of two differential equations. Can you please provide some background. Where does it arise?

Comment: @GiancarloCreanza Perhaps of interest for your research: For the case `r==0` there exist two analytical solutions `1/(1+Exp[x])` and `1/(1-Exp[x])`

Comment: @UlrichNeumann thanks for the comment. However $1-A(x)$ is a cumulative distribution function in my original problem, that's why, in the case $r=0$, I only consider $A(x)=1/(1+e^{x})$ as a solution. By the way thanks for the answers and all the interest in solving this problem!

Comment: @GiancarloCreanza My pleasure, you are welcome!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A small modification of @AlexTrounev 's great answer gives a unique fixedpoint without jumps for `r=0,1,2`!

It's only necessary to modify the iterationpart $\text{fa}_{n+1}(x)=e^{-\text{int}\left(\text{fa}_n(x)\right)}$ .

Here I assume a memory based iteration $\text{fa}_{n+1}(x)=(1-g) e^{-\text{int}\left(\text{fa}_n(x)\right)}+g 
   \text{fa}_n(x)$  (memory parameter `0<g<1`) which works quite well.

Playing around with memory parameter `g` it seems `g=1/4` is a good choice!

```
nlg[r_?NumericQ] := 
  With[{L = 20, g = 1/4}, 
   NestList[
    Function[fa, 
     Block[{int}, 
      int[x_?NumericQ] := 
       Block[{s}, 
        NIntegrate[(x + s)^r fa[s], {s, -x, L}, 
         Method -> {{Automatic, "LocalAdaptive"}[[-1]], 
           "SymbolicProcessing" -> 0}]];
      Interpolation[
       Table[{x, g fa[x] + (1 - g) Exp[-int[x]]}, {x, -L, 
         L, .1}]]]], (1 - Tanh[#])/2 &, 20]];
```

case `r==0`

```
rr = 0;
scale = 100000;
approx = nlg[rr];
Show[{ Plot[  {approx[[-1]][x](*,1/(1+Exp[x])*)}   , {x, -20, 20} , 
   PlotStyle -> {Black(*,{Dashed,Gray}*)}, PlotRange -> All, 
   PlotLegends -> 
    LineLegend[{"approximation(r=" <> ToString[rr] <> ")"}]], 
  Plot[scale ( approx[[-1]][x] - approx [[-2]][x] )  , {x, -20, 20} , 
   PlotStyle -> Red, PlotRange -> All, 
   PlotLegends -> 
    LineLegend[{Style["error * " <> ToString[scale], Red] }]]}, 
 PlotRange -> All, PlotLabel -> "r=" <> ToString[rr]]
```

[image]

This solution agrees very well with the known exact solution `1/(1+Exp[x])`!

case `r==1`

```
rr = 1;
scale = 100000;
approx = nlg[rr];
Show[{ Plot[  {approx[[-1]][x](*,1/(1+Exp[x])*)}   , {x, -20, 20} , 
   PlotStyle -> {Black(*,{Dashed,Gray}*)}, PlotRange -> All, 
   PlotLegends -> 
    LineLegend[{"approximation(r=" <> ToString[rr] <> ")"}]], 
  Plot[scale ( approx[[-1]][x] - approx [[-2]][x] )  , {x, -20, 20} , 
   PlotStyle -> Red, PlotRange -> All, 
   PlotLegends -> 
    LineLegend[{Style["error * " <> ToString[scale], Red] }]]}, 
 PlotRange -> All, PlotLabel -> "r=" <> ToString[rr]]
```

[image]

case `r==2`

```
rr = 2;
scale = 100000;
approx = nlg[rr];
Show[{ Plot[  {approx[[-1]][x](*,1/(1+Exp[x])*)}   , {x, -20, 20} , 
   PlotStyle -> {Black(*,{Dashed,Gray}*)}, PlotRange -> All, 
   PlotLegends -> 
    LineLegend[{"approximation(r=" <> ToString[rr] <> ")"}]], 
  Plot[scale ( approx[[-1]][x] - approx [[-2]][x] )  , {x, -20, 20} , 
   PlotStyle -> Red, PlotRange -> All, 
   PlotLegends -> 
    LineLegend[{Style["error * " <> ToString[scale], Red] }]]}, 
 PlotRange -> All, PlotLabel -> "r=" <> ToString[rr]]
```

[image]

The error( shown in red) between successive iterations is very small (no jumps!)

Hope it helps!

Comment: Nice! Plotting the "error" is possible to tune the parameter $g$, for example for the case $r=2$ it seems that $g=.3$ gives the best result. I also tried to change the input function to see whether the iterative solution is "stable" and it seems ok. Thanks for the interest!

Comment: Tuning of `g` is a nice numerical task. More essential is the fact that my approach gives a unique stable fixedpointsolution for different values of `g`! I think that 's the detailed answer you asked for

Comment: @UlrichNeumann This is nice answer (+1). It looks like the average of 2 solutions. The question is, should there be one solution or 2? For example, a quadratic equation also has 2 solutions.

Comment: @AlexTrounev Thanks! Good question, from an iterative solution I would expect only one solution.  That's why I tried to remember the current approximation (weight `g` ) in my approach

Comment: @AlexTrounev I tried a linear combination of your two solutions too, which gives  `c1 A1[x]+c2 A2[x]== A1[x]^c1*A2[x]^c2` . No idea  how to find optimal parameters `c1,c2` yet.

Answer (score 6):

To solve this problem we can use iterative method described [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/285076/numerically-solving-a-non-linear-integro-differential-equation/285096#285096https://). Unfortunately two conditions at $x=\pm \infty$ are not enough to define unique solution. Numerically we can define 2 solutions as follows

```
With[{L = 20, r = 1}, 
  nl = NestList[
    Function[{fa}, 
     Block[{int}, 
      int[x_?NumericQ] := 
       Block[{s}, 
        r NIntegrate[ (x + s)^(r - 1) fa[s], {s, -x, L}, 
          Method -> {{Automatic, "LocalAdaptive"}[[-1]], 
            "SymbolicProcessing" -> 0}]];
      NDSolveValue[{A'[x] == A[x] (-int[x]), A[-L] == 1}, 
       A, {x, -L, L}]]], 1/(1 + Exp[#]) &, 10]];
```

Visualization

```
With[{L = 20}, {Plot[
   Evaluate[Table[nl[[i]][x], {i, 6, 10, 2}]], {x, -L/2, L/2}, 
   PlotLegends -> Table[i, {i, 6, 10, 2}], Frame -> True, 
   Axes -> False, GridLines -> Automatic], 
  Plot[Evaluate[Table[nl[[i]][x], {i, 5, 9, 2}]], {x, -L/2, L/2}, 
   PlotLegends -> Table[i, {i, 5, 9, 2}], Frame -> True, 
   Axes -> False, GridLines -> Automatic]}]
```

[image: Figure 1]
As we can see solution jumps between two states. Same picture we have for $r=2$

```
With[{L = 20, r = 2}, 
  nl1 = NestList[
    Function[{fa}, 
     Block[{int}, 
      int[x_?NumericQ] := 
       Block[{s}, 
        r NIntegrate[ (x + s)^(r - 1) fa[s], {s, -x, L}, 
          Method -> {{Automatic, "LocalAdaptive"}[[-1]], 
            "SymbolicProcessing" -> 0}]];
      NDSolveValue[{A'[x] == A[x] (-int[x]), A[-L] == 1}, 
       A, {x, -L, L}]]], (1 - Tanh[#])/2 &, 10]];

With[{L = 20}, {Plot[Evaluate[Table[nl1[[i]][x], {i, 6, 10, 2}]], {x, -L/2, L/2}, 
  PlotLegends -> Table[i, {i, 6, 10, 2}], Frame -> True, 
  Axes -> False, GridLines -> Automatic], 
 Plot[Evaluate[Table[nl1[[i]][x], {i, 5, 9, 2}]], {x, -L/2, L/2}, 
  PlotLegends -> Table[i, {i, 5, 9, 2}], Frame -> True, Axes -> False,
   GridLines -> Automatic]}]
```

[image: Figure 2]

Note that for $r=0$ we have functional equation with two solutions as well

```
With[{L = 20, r = 0}, 
  nl0 = NestList[Function[{fa}, Block[{int}, int[x_?NumericQ] := fa[-x];
      NDSolveValue[{A'[x] == A[x] (-int[x]), A[-L] == 1}, 
       A, {x, -L, L}]]], 1/(1 + Exp[2 #]) &, 10]];


With[{L = 20}, {Plot[
   Evaluate[Table[nl0[[i]][x], {i, 6, 10, 2}]], {x, -L/2, L/2}, 
   PlotLegends -> Table[i, {i, 6, 10, 2}], Frame -> True, 
   Axes -> False, GridLines -> Automatic], 
  Plot[Evaluate[Table[nl0[[i]][x], {i, 5, 9, 2}]], {x, -L/2, L/2}, 
   PlotLegends -> Table[i, {i, 5, 9, 2}], Frame -> True, 
   Axes -> False, GridLines -> Automatic]}]
```

[image: Figure 3]

Mean last 2 solutions (solid blue line) we can compare with exact solution $A=1/(1+e^x)$ (red dashed line) as

```
With[{L = 20}, 
 Show[Plot[.5 (nl0[[9]][x] + nl0[[10]][x]), {x, -L/2, L/2}, 
   Frame -> True, Axes -> False, GridLines -> Automatic, 
   PlotStyle -> Blue], 
  Plot[1/(1 + Exp[x]), {x, -L, L}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Dashed}]]]
```

[image: Figure 4]

**Update 1** We can solve equation $A(x)=e^{-\int_{-x}^{\infty}(x+y)^rA(y)dy}$ directly using iterative method as follows

```
With[{L = 20}, 
  nl0 = NestWhileList[
    Function[{fa}, 
     Block[{int}, 
      int[x_?NumericQ] := 
       NIntegrate[fa[y], {y, -x, L}, 
        Method -> {{Automatic, "LocalAdaptive"}[[-1]], 
          "SymbolicProcessing" -> 0}]; 
      Interpolation[
       Table[{x, Exp[-int[x]]}, {x, -L, L, .1}]]]], (1 - Tanh[#])/2 &,
     Abs[#1[0] - #2[0]] > 10^(-9) &, 2, 20]];

nmax = Length[nl0];
With[{L = 20}, 
 Plot[Evaluate[Table[nl0[[i]][x], {i, nmax-1,nmax}]], {x, -L/2, 
   L/2}, PlotLegends -> Automatic, Frame -> True, 
  GridLines -> Automatic]]
```

Here we used `NestWhileList` with convergence criteria, but have two solutions as well.
[image: Figure 5]

Code for arbitrary `r`

```
With[{L = 20, r = 1}, 
  nl1 = NestList[
    Function[fa, 
     Block[{int}, 
      int[x_?NumericQ] := 
       Block[{s}, 
        NIntegrate[ (x + s)^r fa[s], {s, -x, L}, 
         Method -> {{Automatic, "LocalAdaptive"}[[-1]], 
           "SymbolicProcessing" -> 0}]];
      Interpolation[
       Table[{x, Exp[-int[x]]}, {x, -L, L, .1}]]]], (1 - Tanh[#])/2 &,
     20]];
```

**Update 2.** As some explanation for Ulrich result $g=1/4$ we can use convergence criteria automated as follows

```
Table[With[{L = 20}, 
  nl0 = NestWhileList[
    Function[{fa}, 
     Block[{int}, 
      int[x_?NumericQ] := 
       NIntegrate[fa[y], {y, -x, L}, 
        Method -> {{Automatic, "LocalAdaptive"}[[-1]], 
          "SymbolicProcessing" -> 0}]; 
      Interpolation[
       Table[{x, Exp[-int[x]] (1 - g) + g fa[x]}, {x, -L, L, .1}], 
       InterpolationOrder -> 4]]], (1 - Tanh[#])/2 &, 
    Abs[#1[0] - #2[0]] > 10^(-3) &, 2, 20]]; {g, 
  Length[nl0]}, {g, .21, .29, .01}]
(*{{0.21, 12}, {0.22, 10}, {0.23, 10}, {0.24, 8}, {0.25, 8}, {0.26, 
  8}, {0.27, 6}, {0.28, 10}, {0.29, 11}}*)
```

We can also plot this list to see the optimal `g`

```
ListLinePlot[%]
```

[image: Figure 6]

As we can see the optimal `g=0.27` means minimal number of iterations to pass criterium $|f_n(0)-f_{n-1}(0)|<10^{-3}$. The corresponding solution for `r=0,1,2`

```
Do[With[{L = 20, g = 0.27}, 
   nl[r] = NestWhileList[
     Function[{fa}, 
      Block[{int}, 
       int[x_?NumericQ] := 
        NIntegrate[(x + y)^r fa[y], {y, -x, L}, 
         Method -> {{Automatic, "LocalAdaptive"}[[-1]], 
           "SymbolicProcessing" -> 0}]; 
       Interpolation[
        Table[{x, Quiet[Exp[-int[x]]] (1 - g) + g fa[x]}, {x, -L, 
          L, .1}], InterpolationOrder -> 4]]], (1 - Tanh[#])/2 &, 
     Abs[#1[0] - #2[0]] > 10^(-3) &, 2, 20]];, {r, 0, 2, 1}]
With[{L = 20}, 
 Plot[Evaluate[Table[nl[r][[-1]][x], {r, 0, 2, 1}]], {x, -L/2, L/2}, 
  PlotLegends -> {0, 1, 2}, Frame -> True, GridLines -> Automatic]]
```

[image: Figure 7]

Comment: Yours second code dosen't work for `r=2` ? I have **no** Plot ?I tried with MMA 13.3.

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk Thank you. Don't forget to add parameter `L=20;` before plot. Anyway post has been updated using `With[]`.

Comment: Ok works fine now. Thanks

Comment: @AlexTrounev Nice answer!!! Does iterative solution also jump for case `r==0` ?

Comment: @UlrichNeumann Thank you for your code and question.  I add case for $r=0$. As you can see the iterative solution jumps in this case as well.

Comment: @AlexTrounev Perhaps condition `A[-L]==1` is to strong? Perhaps `A[-L]+A[L]==1` might help???

Comment: Thanks @AlexTrounev for the answer. I waited so long to mark the answer as correct since I was trying to understand all the code well. As we can see the problems of iterative solutions are the initial input function and also boundary conditions. I'm trying to find a way to solve the case $r=0$ without relying on the mean between the two different output of the iterations and then look at the cases $r=1$ and $r=2$.

Comment: @UlrichNeumann Actually as I understand there are two solutions without special condition like `A[0]==1/2` for`r=0`. But we don't know what condition should be for $r=1, 2$.

Comment: Your two figures: the last one and 3rd from the end seems to contradict each other. But the last figure is in agreement with my results.

Comment: @yarchik In Figure 5 shown nonconvergent solution, while in the last Figure shown convergent solution.

Answer (score 5):

### Initial solution idea

Your integral equation can be reduced to an interesting system of differential equations, at least in $r=1$ case. Since $A(x)>0$ we can write $A(x)=e^{a(x)}$.  Therefore
$$
a(x)=-\int_{-x}^{\infty}(x+y)e^{a(y)}dy.
$$
Differentiate:

```
 D[-Integrate[(x + y) E^a[y], {y, -x, Infinity}], {x, 2}]
```

$$
a''(x)=-e^{a(-x)}.
$$
Let us now denote $b(x)=a(-x)$. In principle, we should demand continuity at $x=0$
$$
a(0)=b(0)=c,\\
a'(0)=-b'(0)=d.
$$
My thanks to @UlrichNeumann for correcting the sign in my second equation.

However, I do not know how to realize this numerically.
Therefore, I will demonstrate a very rough approximation. Notice, that the motivation is to show a different approach. I am fully aware of the fact that there are issues that are hard to solve in general.

The first simplification is to replace the semi-infinite interval
$(-\infty,0]$ with $[-l, 0]$.

The second simplification is to specify only the boundary values of functions and their derivatives at $x=-l$. We know that, in $a(-\infty)=0, a'(-\infty)=0$ and $b(-\infty)=-\infty$ and $b'(-\infty)=0$. In the finite interval, we replace infinite values with finite ones, selected by tries and errors (poor man shooting method) in such a way that $a(0)\approx b(0)$.

```
l = 5;
{u, v} = NDSolveValue[
  D[a[x], {x, 2}] == -Exp[b[x]] && D[b[x], {x, 2}] == -Exp[a[x]] && 
   a[-l] == 0 && a'[-l] == 0 && b[-l] == -20 && b'[-l] == 6.46, {a, b}, 
   {x, -l, 0}]

w[x_] := v[-x]
g1 = Plot[{Exp[u[x]]}, {x, -l, 0}, PlotRange -> All, 
  PlotTheme -> {"Web", "Scientific"}];
g2 = Plot[{, Exp[w[x]]}, {x, 0, l}, PlotRange -> All, 
  PlotTheme -> {"Web", "Scientific"}];
Show[{g1, g2}]
```

[image]

### Improved solution for $r=1$

The question of @UlrichNeumann inspired me to generate a fully automatic and very accurate solution.

```
l = 5;
{u, v} = 
 NDSolveValue[{D[a[x], {x, 2}] == -Exp[b[x]], 
   D[b[x], {x, 2}] == -Exp[a[x]], a[-l] == 0, a'[-l] == 0, 
   a[0] == b[0], -a'[0] == b'[0]}, {a, b}, {x, -l, 0}]

A[x_] := Piecewise[{{Exp[u[x]], x <= 0}, {Exp[v[-x]], x > 0}}]
```

[image]

### Improved solution for $r=2$

Here I use the same method for
$$
a(x)=-\int_{-x}^{\infty}(x+y)^2e^{a(y)}dy.
$$
A differential equation can be obtained by differentiating this identity 3 times.

```
D[-Integrate[(x + y)^2 E^a[y], {y, -x, Infinity}], {x, 3}]
```

yielding $a'''(x)=-2 e^{a(-x)}$. Introducing as before $b(x)=a(-x)$ I obtain
$$
\begin{aligned} 
a'''(x)&=-2 e^{b(x)},\\
b'''(x)&=+2 e^{a(x)},\\
a^{(n)}(-l)&=0,\\
b^{(n)}(0)&=(-1)^n a^{(n)}(0),
\end{aligned} 
$$
for $n=0,1,2$.

```
l = 5;
{u, v} = 
 NDSolveValue[{D[a[x], {x, 3}] == -2 Exp[b[x]], 
   D[b[x], {x, 3}] == 2 Exp[a[x]], a[-l] == 0, a'[-l] == 0, 
   a''[-l] == 0, a[0] == b[0], -a'[0] == b'[0], a''[0] == b''[0]}, {a,
    b}, {x, -l, 0}]
```

[image]

Comment: Your first `Differentiate`   covers only the case `r==0`. This case has a general solution `1/(1+Exp[x])`!

Comment: Note that for the $r = 2$ case the equation simply (?) becomes $a'''(x) = -2 e^{a(-x)}$.

Comment: @yarchik Thanks for re-presenting your approach, very interesting. Two remarks: #1  I think your second continuity condition should be `-a'[0]==b'[0]` . #2 I would expect `NDSolveValue[{D[a[x], {x, 2}] == -Exp[b[x]], 
  D[b[x], {x, 2}] == -Exp[a[x]], a[-l] == 1 , b[-l] == 0 , 
  a[0] == b[0], -a'[0] == b'[0]}, {a, b}, {x, -l, 0} ]` for the correct  system? I tried the modifications but result isn't ok

Comment: @UlrichNeumann #1 Right, thanks for correcting my mistake. #2 The correct condition is a[-l]=0. That is because $A(-l) =1 =e^{a(-l)}$. #2 The problem with this approach is that the Sturm-Liouville problem is more difficult than the initial value problem. That is why I have chosen the second path.

Comment: @Yarchik Thanks for your reply. Your improved solution is great. Now it's possible to confirm the iterative approach `r>0 (continous)` for some values of `r`

Comment: @Yarchik I'm  wondering why Mathematica `DSolve` doesn't find the analytic solution case `r==0` : `DSolve [{a'[x] == -E^b[x], b'[x] ==  E^a[x]  }, {a, b}, x ]`. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: @UlrichNeumann My MA version 13.1 complains that inverse functions are being used and returns a solution that does not match the boundary conditions. It suggests to use `Reduce`. But I do not know how to use it inside `DSolve`.

Comment: @yarchik Thanks. Same with Mathematica 12.2

Comment: @yarchik This is nice solution (+1).