# How to solve this integral equation numerically?

Tags: equation-solving, numerical-integration, numerics, integral-equations

I am encountering difficulties while trying to numerically solve an equation in Mathematica that involves an unknown function and an integral. Specifically, the equation takes the form of
\begin{equation}
f(z)=g(z)+\int_{z}^1\mathrm{d}y\,g\left(1-\frac{z}{y}\right)\frac{1}{y}f(y),\quad z\in(0,1),
\end{equation}
where $g(z)$ is a known function, and $f(z)$ is the unknown function I am attempting to solve for. It requires for any $g(z)$, you should have a corresponding solution for $f(z)$.

I tried a specific $g(z)$:

```
g[z_] := z
equation[z_] := f[z] == g[z] + Integrate[g[1 - z/y]/y*f[y], {y, z, 1}]
solution = NSolve[{equation[z]}, f, {z, 0, 1}]
result[z_] := f[z] /. solution[[1]]
```

But it didn't work.

Comment: You are looking for a numerical solution for unknown function `g[z]`? Isn't that a contradiction?

Comment: No, I want to solve f[z], and g[z] is a known function, however I don’t know how g[z] looks like. So I just set it as an unknown function. I know it seems wired but this is the problem.

Comment: `g[z]` is an undefined function and you're looking for a numerical solution? That's the contradiction!

Comment: Yes, you are right. I reread the question and made an edit on my question.

Comment: Ok, but be aware that the function domain of  `g[y]`  is  `-Infinity<y<0`!

Comment: I think you will need something [like this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/285076/numerically-solving-a-non-linear-integro-differential-equation/285110#285110), but in reverse, like a Riemann sum going backwards. We know that f[1] == g[1], as the integral is zero at z==1. So we can might be able to take a small delta _backwards_ from z=1 and _subtract_ the sum of the contribution of the last rectangle to get an estimate for f[1 - n*d]

Comment: I believe that you meant `DSolve` instead of `NSolve` in the code.  `NSolve` finds roots of polynomials and some other functions.  `NDSolve` cannot solve integral equations.  And, in this case `DSolve` is not up to the task.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although the general problem in the question probably requires the methods referenced by flinty in [285076](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/285076/1063), the specific problem contained in the question's code, `g[z] = z` can be solved as follows.  Write the integral equation as

```
eq = f[z] - z - Integrate[(1 - z/y)/y*f[y], {y, z, 1}];
```

Now twice differentiate `eq`

```
deq = D[eq, {z, 2}]
(* -f[z]/z^2 + f''[z] *)
```

construct boundary conditions

```
bc0 = eq /. z -> 1
{* -1 + f[1] *}
bc1 = D[eq, z] /. z -> 1
(* -1 + f'[1] *)
```

and solve with `DSolve`

```
DSolve[{deq == 0, bc0 == 0, bc1 == 0}, f, z] // Flatten
(* {f -> Function[{z}, 1/10 z^(1/2 - Sqrt[5]/2) 
   (5 - Sqrt[5] + 5 z^Sqrt[5] + Sqrt[5] z^Sqrt[5])]} *)
```

This solution can be verified by back-substitution.

```
Simplify[eq /. %, 0 < z < 1]
(* 0 *)
```

Added note: The approach here should work for any `g[z]` that is a polynomial or can be approximated accurately by one.  The order of the resulting ODE would be one greater than the order of the polynomial.  Of course, obtaining a symbolic solution, as accomplished here, might not be possible. Numerical solutions of the resulting ODE would be possible except near `z = 0`, where the solutions typically would be singular.  Even the symbolic solution obtained for `g[z] = z` is singular there.

Comment: Thank you sir! It works well! I'm new to mma and I got invaluable experience from your answer.